# The variable that read from txtfile can't be assigned using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to read 3 variables from `txtfile` using this code :

```
stop();
import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.text.Font;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Direction;
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import flashx.textLayout.factory.StringTextLineFactory;
//---------------------
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
var ip:String;
var port:String;
var margin:Number;

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
ip=e.target.data.ip;
port=e.target.data.port;
margin=e.target.data.margin;
trace(e.target.data.ip);
trace(e.target.data.port);
gotoAndPlay(2);
}
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("example.txt"));
//---------------------
```

I put this code in the first frame in frame 2 i use the variables (ip,port,margin) but they are null!!!why ?

frame 2 action code:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(ip+":"+port+"/Default.aspx?EndStation=22&&direction=right&&lineid=1&&command=all&&");
```

The output error:

```
/Default.aspx?EndStation=22&&direction=right&&lineid=1&&command=all&&nocache=1412331762086'
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost

:46049
```

I use `trace` and the variables is read by my code .

Best regards

Comment: Try putting a trace() in your frame 2 script to see what ip, port, and the other variables are at the time of execution. You may also want to cast/convert your variables to strings, when you build your URLRequest, just to be on the safe side. Also try building your URL string in a separate variable and then use that variable within the URLRequest. This will allow you to also trace out the string that you are building, prior to its use.

Comment: @C.Parcell i did ,var res:String;
res=ip.toString()+":"+port.toString()+"/Default.aspx?EndStation=22&&direction=right&&lineid=1&&command=all&&";The ip and port in frame 2 are correct

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "http://" in front of your request url string.